# Access Database with SQL Server Backend: Dramatic Slow Down with Multiple Users

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I've migrated an Access 2007 database to a SQL Server 2008 R2 backend, retaining the Access front end with linked tables.  Performance was fine with a few users.

Yesterday the application was opened up to multiple users and in the afternoon the performance went to hell.  Took literally minutes for the front end to open or close, or do anything.  The delay in closing seemed particularly strange, as it's done via a button on the main menu that just calls Application.Quit.  Doesn't do anything else at all.

I found the old LDBView utility seemed to work on the .laccdb file.  It was showing 11 users logged on plus another 15 that were no longer logged in.  It didn't show user names, just the machine names they were connecting from.  Mostly those machine names were two virtual hosts so I don't know if they were actually different users or the same user being reported multiple times (don't know enough about the format of .laccdb files to be able to tell).

I took a copy of the troublesome Access front end file (the .accdb file) and ran the copy from the same network location as the original.  It ran fine.  So the problem does not seem to be in the network, or in the SQL Server database, or that the Access front end is corrupt somehow.

Eliminating those possibilities, the problem seems to be related to multiple users using the same Access front end simultaneously.  The original Access database, before the tables were migrated to SQL Server, worked fine for the same number of users.  So the fundamental design of the front end seems to be able to support multiple users.

How would I go about tracking down the source of contention issues in the Access front end?  To me it seems there is no visibility of what is going on, apart from viewing the number of concurrent users in the .laccdb file.

By the way, since the original Access database worked fine with multiple users, I've been told there is no way each user can have their own copy of the Access front end, as it would be a maintenance nightmare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The users should not be using the same front-end copy. They should each have their own copy which they can save in their personal drive.

You keep your own copy of the front-end, make your modifications to it, and then redistribute it to the users, to replace their old version.

Sharing a single front-end copy is a definite no-no. This is the nightmare.. and is the most likely cause of the issues you are having.

Comment: Thanks Andy.  Unfortunately that's not an option at the moment.  The big problem is the original Access database worked with multiple concurrent users and the powers that be think the migrated Access application with SQL Server back end should not be more difficult to use or maintain than the original.  I often wonder if it would have been simpler to migrate the database and rewrite the front end using LightSwitch or Alpha Five.  But that would have required a major redesign of the interface, given the interactions between the forms.

Comment: Manager has agreed to deploy separate Access front ends for each user.  This morning had 11 concurrent users in single copy of front end without problem but better safe than sorry.

Comment: That's good. I had no other suggestion for you, other than to take an extended holiday ;). I have kept a front-end folder on the server, numbered these front-ends, and instructed users to copy the most recent version to their personal drive. If you don't trust them to do this then you could email them their copy, with instructions on how to copy it to their personal drive, or locally.

Comment: When I'm modifying the front-end I also copy it locally, work on it, then number it and copy it back to the front-ends folder. You must insist that they copy their front-end copy, not use the one on the shared drive!

Comment: There's an added twist for us:  Most users are in one city, the SQL Server is in another.  The two sites are connected via a WAN.  One of the users tried running the Access front end locally.  Far too much latency.  So we've now got multiple copies of the Access front end on a terminal server on the same LAN as the SQL Server.  IT operations has given users shortcuts, with different shortcuts pointing to different copies of the front end on the terminal server.  They're putting together a batch file to copy any new release to each of the front end copies on the terminal server.

Comment: Put the server on a bus and take it to the other city ;)